# How to get an average number of rows grouped by matched column?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, aggregate-functions

I have a motorsport database and need to create a query to find the average number of total pitstops per race(name), per year.
Each row is a pitstop and I have made a count of how many pitstops happen per year.

My current query is:

```
SELECT   
pitstopRaceName AS raceName,  
(SELECT AVG(COUNT(pitstopRaceDate))) AS totalPitstop  
FROM MoSpo_PitStop  
GROUP BY pitstopRaceName ,pitstopRaceDate  
ORDER BY pitstopRaceName
```

and that gives the result:

| raceName | totalPitstop |
| --- | --- |
| British Grand Prix | 1.0000 |
| British Grand Prix | 6.0000 |
| British GT Championship | '2.0000 |
| German Grand Prix | 5.0000 |
| German Grand Prix | 1.0000 |
| German Grand Prix | 4.0000 |
| Italian Grand Prix | 1.0000 |
| Italian Grand Prix | 5.0000 |

where each row is its own year, i just haven't included them in the query

But what i need is all race names to average their total pitstops, for example British Grand Prix would average 6 and 1 to get 3.5, Italian Grand Prix to average 1 and 5 to get 3 and so on.
I cannot work out how to get this done any would appreciate any help.

Comment: Edit your question and show what the *source* data looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what i need is all race names to average their total pitstops, for example British Grand Prix would average 6 and 1 to get 3.5, Italian Grand Prix to average 1 and 5 to get 3 and so on

I suspect that you want two levels of aggregation. First by year and race, so we can count the pit stops, then by race only, to compute the yearly average per race:

```
select race_name, avg(cnt_pitstops) as avg_pitsops_per_year
from (
    select year(pitstopracedate) as race_year,
        pitstopracename as race_name, 
        count(*) as cnt_pitstops
    from mospo_pitstop
    group by race_year, race_name
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can count the number of pit stops and divide by the number of years:

```
select pitstopRaceName,
       count(*) / count(distinct pitstopRaceDate)
from MoSpo_PitStop ps
group by pitstopRaceName;
```

If the `pitstopRaceDate` does not define the race, you can use just the year:

```
select pitstopRaceName,
       count(*) / count(distinct year(pitstopRaceDate))
from MoSpo_PitStop ps
group by pitstopRaceName;
```